# Some blocked websites won't open even with VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy

In my country many websites like Youtube are blocked. By connecting to a VPN I can access many of them, But some of them still won't work. The loading takes a long time and after some time it shows Timeout Error. 
I have ubuntu alongside Windows 10, The VPN works perfectly in Windows on the same WiFi network and all websites including Youtube are accessible.

Would that be a DNS problem? (I entered the IP directly and no luck again) If not, What could that be?

P.S. proxy is set to none.

Comment: Is it a Ubuntu specific problem. Something, that is working with WIn 10?

Comment: BTW, is your MTU set correctly?

Comment: @kukulo Yes, VPN works in Windows 10. In Windows, all sites including Youtube show up. I read some forums which recommended setting MTU to something, I did it but didn't work again. BTW I don't really know what MTU is.

Comment: Please check the answer. You will need to set your MTU (Maximum transmission unit) correctly. The MTU specifies the maximal packet length in bytes when transmitting information over a specific device. Some PPoE connections have lower MTU than the standard settings.

Comment: If it is a pptp VPN, see also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007171/no-internet-over-vpn-connection.

Answer (score 0):

When using PPoE, VPN connection, one common problem is to set correct MTU on the Ethernet connection.

Use **ping** command to determine your MTU:

```
ping -M do -s 1472 youtube.com
```

If the result is (result = "Frag needed and DF set") then go with lower number in the ping command:

```
ping -M do -s 1462 youtube.com
```

until you get reply to your ping command (result = reply).

Write down the Number - this will be your MTU.

Now set up the new MTU (your Number) on your ethernet connection as in this question:

[How do I change the MTU value on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230926/how-do-i-change-the-mtu-value-on-ubuntu)