# apt-get cannot connect to Ubuntu main archives

Tags: networking, apt

I started my journey with `apt-get update`. I received error message

```
Err:1 http://ke.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to ke.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2c0f:fe40:8001:10::1). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) 
  Could not connect to ke.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (197.155.77.1), connection timed out
```

Then I followed the possible solution in [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198621/apt-get-cannot-connect-to-ubuntu-archives). I edited `/etc/apt/sources.list` to replace `ke.archive.ubuntu.com` with `archive.ubuntu.com` which is the main server. The new error was now:

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::102). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::101). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::103). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.82), connection timed out 
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.83), connection timed out 
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out 
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.81), connection timed out 
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out
```

I even tried forcing IP4 with command `apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update`, but got error message:

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out 
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.81), connection timed out 
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out 
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.82), connection timed out 
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.83), connection timed out
```

This tells me that the previous attempt tried both IP6 and IP4.

I also tried editing `/etc/resolv.conf` to change nameserver to `8.8.8.8` and then to `1.1.1.1` but no change. Even tried uncommenting all.

1. The command `ping -c 4 archive.ubuntu.com` gives `4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3000ms`
2. The command `nslookup archive.ubuntu.com` gives the IP addresses above
3. I am connected to the system via SSH

What else can I do to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Please, try to check repositories by web browser. Copy the repository name to address field in browser and open the page, e.g. `http//ke.archive.ubuntu.com` or `http://archive.ubuntu.com` . Is it possible to open the page and to see an Index?

Comment: Like I said, I access the system via SSH.. so no web browser or GUI for that matter..
That being said, I tried `wget http://archive.ubuntu.com` which is the cli command for your browser suggestion, and I get `Resolving ...`, `Connecting ...connected.` and then `Connection timed out.`. There might be a solution here, Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to download other web pages? Try `wget https://yahoo.com/index.php` and check content of index.php file.

Comment: all `wget` commands timeout.

Comment: I can think of two possible causes: an error in the HTTP (HTTPS) processing, e.g. firewall with bad HTTP inspection, or a low MTU value. Try connecting to an external FTP server:  `ftp test.rebex.net` login=demo, password=password and then independently check your MTU size using destination `archive.ubuntu.com` according  the **MTU verifying** chapter in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393338/how-to-set-mtu-permanently-in-cli

Comment: `ifconfig` shows `mtu 1500` and `ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -c 2 -M do -s 2000` yields `ping: local error: message too long, mtu=1500`. UFW is disabled.